# I want to pull a number from a list inside another list, how do I do it?

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is my list

```
ab = [[1,2,3],[1,4,6],[5,86,3],[9,8,7],[12,98,13]]
```

and I want to check if a number is in that list

```
sa= 5
```

and if it exists I want to make changes (e.g. remove it) and become:

```
ad = [[1,2,3],[1,4,6],[86,3],[9,8,7],[12,98,13]]
```

this is my actual program:

```
import random

lista=[]
def fun():
    for i in range(1,80):
        lista.insert(i,i)
    return lista

#dimiourgia pexton me 5 ari8mous alla xoris onoma
pextes=[]
for i in range (1,100):
    lista=[]
    fun()
    fivenum=[]
    for j in range(1,5):
        pick=(random.choice(lista))
        lista.remove(pick)
        fivenum.insert(j,pick)
    pextes.insert(i,fivenum)
print pextes

lista=[]
fun()
for i in range(1,80):
    lucknum=(random.choice(lista))
    lista.remove(lucknum)
    for j in range(1,100):
        steal=lista[j]
        for k in range(1,5):
            if lucknum in lista[j,k]:
                print "yes!!!!"
            else:
                print "hmmmmmm"
```

I am stuck even at the search inside the list/s.

Comment: Not sure what the program is supposed to do, but if all you want is to remove the number, this can be done in one line using a list comprehension `ad_new = [[y for y in x if y not in [5]] for x in ad]`

Answer (score 2):

You can use a nested list comprehension:

```
ab = [[1,2,3],[1,4,6],[5,86,3],[9,8,7],[12,98,13]]
sa= 5
new_ab = [[b for b in i if b != sa] for i in ab]
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 4, 6], [86, 3], [9, 8, 7], [12, 98, 13]]
```

Or, `filter` can be used with a `lambda` function:

```
new_ab = [filter(lambda x:x != sa, i) for i in ab]
```

Comment: Shoot, you beat me to it. I didn't even consider filter and lambda because I think list comprehensions are much easier on the eye (and brain).

Comment: @MarkM List comprehensions are much cleaner, and slightly more efficient in when run on smaller input samples.